# Python Skipping iteration

Tags: python, skip, continue

I am using a Tkinter python 2.6 UI and I am trying trying to use a button to skip though an elememt in a list of commands if a particular command takes too long. Essentially I trying to execute the 'continue' statement from another function. Consider the following:

```
def executeCommands(commands):
    for cmd in commands:
        sendCommand(cmd)


#arbitrary button class used as an example  
class Button(self)

    #this button executes onSkip() method when clicked
    self.skipBtn = Button('skip', command=self.onSkip)

    def onSkip(self):
        #skip to next iteration of loop that was being iterated prior to skip button execution
```

How would I get the executeCommands method to stop what its doing and skip to the next cmd when the onSkip method from the Button class is executed?

Comment: Damn, Python 2.6? You sure your `import time; time.time()` is working properly?

Comment: For a button to work while a function runs you will need some kind of threading. Do you have that already? Can you show it to us?

Comment: The Button is a widget made available by the Tkinter UI plug in. (i.e. import Tkinter)

Comment: The code provided is not operational code used, it is provided as an attempt to simply providing a visual reference of the task I am trying to accomplish

Comment: @David: *"execute the 'continue' statement from another function"*: Call inside `def onSkip(...` the `continue statement of the other function`.

Comment: @stovfl That is what I am trying to do; however I cannot figure out how to do that. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @David: *"skip though an elememt"*: You mean, **kill** `sendCommand(cmd)`? I assume you have **no access** to the code of `sendCommand(`. Therefore `sendCommand(...` have to be a [`Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread) or [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate)